# psycopg COPY command for large dataset taking forever

Tags: postgresql, psycopg2

I have 2 different databases where I need to copy the data between one database to another.
I'm using the following code:

```
with psycopg.connect(dsn_src) as conn1, \
    psycopg.connect(dsn_tgt) as conn2:
    with conn1.cursor().copy("COPY " + table + " TO STDOUT (FORMAT BINARY)") as copy1:
        with conn2.cursor().copy("COPY " + table + " FROM STDIN (FORMAT BINARY)") as copy2:
            for data in copy1:
                copy2.write(data)
```

The problem is that I'm copying around 10M+ rows, and it seems that the loop takes forever. Is there any way to improve the performance?

Comment: 1) I would not use `FORMAT BINARY`. 2) Assuming you are using Python 3.8+ I would change `for data in copy1:` to `while data := f.read(1000):` per [psycopg COPY](https://www.psycopg.org/psycopg3/docs/basic/copy.html#copy) *Copying block-by-block*. Where 1000 represents block size and can be changed if necessary.

Answer (score 2):

1. Pipe [`pg_dump`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/app-pgdump.html) to [`psql`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/app-psql.html) to copy the table using PostgreSQL native format.

   ```bash
   pg_dump -h source_db_host -p source_db_port -U source_db_user \
       --schema='your_schema'                                    \
       --table='your_schema.your_table' source_db_name           \
   | psql -h target_db_host -p target_db_port -U target_db_user  \
       -v ON_ERROR_STOP=1 target_db_name                         \
   &>> your_table.clone.log  &
   ```
2. Multithreaded `pg_dump` first with high compression, then multithreaded `pg_restore`:

   ```bash
   pg_dump -Z9 -Fd -h 127.0.0.1 -p 5432 --verbose --jobs=16 \
   --schema 'source_schema' --table='source_schema.source_table' \
   -U source_user source_dbname -f transfer_file_name \
   > source_table.backup.log 2>&1 &

   pg_restore -h target_db_host -p 5432 -U target_user \
   --dbname=target_db_name --format=d --exit-on-error \
   --verbose --jobs=16 transfer_file_name \
   &>> source_table.restore.14.log &
   ```
3. Use [`postgres_fdw`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/postgres-fdw.html) to link it as a foreign table to make it accessible, without having to physically write it the second time on
   the target.

   ```sql
   CREATE EXTENSION IF NOT EXISTS postgres_fdw;

   CREATE SERVER source_db FOREIGN DATA WRAPPER postgres_fdw 
   OPTIONS (host '127.0.0.1', dbname 'source_db_name', port '5432');

   CREATE USER MAPPING FOR your_user_on_target SERVER source_db
   OPTIONS (user 'your_user_on_source', password 'your_password');

   CREATE SCHEMA schema_linked_from_source;

   IMPORT FOREIGN SCHEMA schema_on_source LIMIT TO (table_on_source)
   FROM SERVER source_db INTO schema_linked_from_source;
   ```

   Similar idea with [`dblink`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/dblink.html).
4. Set up [replication](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/logical-replication.html) to stream the data continuously.
5. Play around with [alternative `psycopg` insertion methods](https://hakibenita.com/fast-load-data-python-postgresql#results-summary).

Comment: For your (1) solution, does it transfer the data directly from the source db -> dest db, or is it source db -> local pc -> dest db ? Because the connection between local pc and the db is a bit slow... I tried with (2), but using pgadmin GUI, and it is stuck when restoring the file... For (3), I don't have the superuser privilege to create extension.. For (5), will explore on it.

Comment: **1)** db1>pg_dump>psql>db2, process wise. Network wise, it's up to you to run this on the system db1 and/or db2 run on, or elsewhere, and same goes for 2, 5 and the code you showed. **3)** and **4)** link db1 to db2 directly, but superuser is required.